# How was Deke Simmons married to Mimi Corcoran

Tags: plot-explanation, 11.22.63

In episode 7 of the show [*11.22.63*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2879552/) Jake is recovering from amnesia and has the following interaction with Deke Simmons

> **Jake:** Thanks, Frank. 
>   **Deke:** It's Deke, son. Deke Simmons.
>   **Jake:** I know. *You're married to Miz Mimi.* 
>   **[sentimental music]** 
>   **Jake:** Uh... I'm sorry. Did I get that wrong? 
>   **Deke:** Miz Mimi passed.

[Full transcript here](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=571&t=26259)

Anyway, **my question is how was Deke married to Mimi?** She is African American and Deke is caucasian and interracial marriage was illegal in Texas until 1967.

Comment: I know nothing about this show, but could it be that they just got married in another state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a mistake of the writers. In fact, a double mistake.

Firstly, in [the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11/22/63) Deke and Mimi indeed married, but the book Mimi wasn't Afro-American, so there were no obstacles preventing the marriage.

Secondly, in the TV show there was no mentioning of Deke and Mimi being married. In fact in episode 6 she [said](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=11-22-63-2016&episode=s01e06) quite the opposite:

> -You believe me when I tell you I love Deke and he loves me?
>
> -Yes, ma'am.
>
> -Deke and I have spent our lives next to one another. Not with one another.

In addition to the above, in the book Jake's memory loss after being beaten is much more severe (chapter 26). For a long time he doesn't remember Deke and refers to him as *A Man In A Cowboy Hat*. When he finally recalls who Deke is he uses a very similar line to the one cited in the question.

It is of course possible that Deke and Mimi married secretly, in another state or in fact never married and Jake only thought so due to his amnesia.

However based on the above book information the most plausible theory is that the writers made an error during adapting the source material. It seems that they used the line from the book without realising that not only the marriage didn't happen in the TV show, but also that legally it wasn't even possible.

Comment: Upon revisiting this I realized that its entirely possible that Jake was simply remembering them being married simply because they were so close. They don't confirm him when we says "you're married to Miz Mimi" and instead simply inform him that she has passed. To Jake it wouldn't be strange for them to be married but obviously they would have thought such a thing very taboo and try to avoid the topic and possibly attribute his comment to his not being quite all there. The point being that just because Jake was remembering them as married doesn't mean they were.

Comment: @As I wrote it's possible that Jake only thought that they were married and that was my initial thought after reading your question, knowing that the marriage didn't happen in the TV show. Then I took the book from the shelf, started analysing and came to a completely different conclusion :-)

Comment: Right, I think both are plausible. The only thing that doesn't fit with the "Jake made a mistake" explanation is that the actor's don't give any indication that what he's just said is incorrect or embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

In episode 6, Jake and Mimi have a conversation where she reveals she has cancer and talks about Deke, saying "we've spend our lives next to one another, but not with one another" or something along those lines. I assumed it was a secret marriage/unofficial one or something.